Cross button not working, package not installing, firefox not running, app store, software update app not working
Problem starts when i tried to close to chrome through cross button but it didn't get close. I face this situation previously, so i try to solve it by running cmd like: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y, sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean -y,and sudo apt install --fix-broken -y, but this time, it doesn't work. So i uninstall chrome try to install it with firefox browser. Now i came to know that firefox also not opening .So i tried to install some package to see what exactly is the issuse but the package are not installing. now i there is not search engine in my ubuntu.Then i try to update or download some app from app store. it also showing me error. Now tell me how should i fix all of this.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 version.

Your question is unclear.

This is very confusing. Please ask a single clear question about what is wrong. You have not even stated a version of Ubuntu. Have a look at this link and after edit the question and add some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
